# jquery on keypress works only if e.which is 13

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault;
        console.log('323');
    }
});
```

the above works fine
but for example `e.which  == 107` or `109` or `27` - doesn't work

`e.keyCode` instead of `e.which` - doesn't help

`on('.keyup'` instead of `on('keypress` - works
but I need `keypress` because of repeating the `console.log` endlessly while the key is pressed
please help

Comment: What you mean by "works fine".  What are you expecting to happen here?  What happens instead?

Comment: Use the keydown event to catch escape (27) and other keys. To avoid repeating, store the value of e.which and conditionally execute the code block only when e.which !== last value.

Comment: @Yogi - `keydown` solves everything. Thanks a lot. You should write the answer